# What are some "just" usages?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I have seen this question:

> ‘I have just been speaking to him.’ In this sentence just is used
>
> A to describe an unfinished action.
>
> B to highlight when the action was done.
>
> C to show a repeated action.

Edit: So what is the correct answer?
I am guessing A or B.

However, I am feeling that it indicates something else like I have been speaking to only one person. So what if I want to highlight this point as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context for the sentence, there are at least three possibilities.

**First possibility:**

You are very close with (A) and (B).  The exact meaning for "just" is to emphasize that the action happened *in the very recent past*.  Another example with more context would be:

1. A man arrives at a party.
2. One minute later, someone asks him, "Is John here?"
3. The man answers, "I don't know, I *just* arrived."

**Second possibility:**

You noted,

> I am feeling that it indicates something else like I have been
>   speaking to only one person.

This could also be correct.  If the person meant this, there would probably be an emphasis on the last word:

"I have *just* been speaking to **him.**"  (perhaps pointing as well, for more emphasis)

But only seeing the words in print, and not hearing inflection or seeing a gesture, it's hard to be certain.

**Third possibility:**

"Just" could also be a way to emphasize that the person was speaking, but took no other action.  This is why more context is needed to be certain.  For example,

"This man claims you made a threatening move against him."

"No, that's not true.  I have *just* been speaking to him."

Comment: Great answer.  I’d add that possibility #2 can also be written “I’ve been speaking to just him”; where possibility #1 and #3 cannot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, depending on it I can infer that the best answer is B in the question. Is that right?

Comment: @GamalThomas, yes, if a choice must be made of "just" those three :) then I think the most likely is (B).